# Downgrading php from 5.4.9 to 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.3 w/ PDO and MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.3. My objective is to downgrade php from 5.4.9 to 5.3.3, with PDO support (for Magento). Magento isn't working. Furthermore, phpmyadmin isn't working because it complains the mysqli extension isn't installed.

Here's my phpinfo
`http://69.195.198.165/phpinfo.php`

Magento error message:
`http://69.195.198.165/errors/report.php?id=1018227680846&skin=default`

installed so far with yum:

```
[root@server etc]# rpm -qa | grep php
php-frameworks-1.0.3-1.noarch
php-cli-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

phpmysql error message
    `http://69.195.198.165/vps/mysql_admin/index.php`

Here's what I get when I try to install php-mysql

```
>root@server etc]# yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.itc.virginia.edu
 * epel: mirror.umd.edu
 * extras: mirror.liberty.edu
 * updates: mirror.umd.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: MySQL-shared-5.1.63-1.glibc23.x86_64 (servergrove-rhel-6)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: MySQL-shared-5.1.63-1.glibc23.x86_64 (servergrove-rhel-6)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake...any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the conflicting third-party `servergrove` repository which is blocking your installation. (Not to mention probably causing all sorts of other trouble.)

Comment: your answer led me down the right path--fixed. thanks a ton.